# New to Spring unable to get controller working

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to Spring and have looked at countless examples and cannot figure out this problem. The issue that I have is that when I click the link from my index.jsp page it does not forward to the hello.jsp page. I do not know why. I have spent 2 days looking up examples and trying countless examples trying to determine what the problem is to no avail. I am hoping you can tell me what the issue is. I am using NetBeans 7.2, Tomcat 7, JDK 7, Spring 3.2.1. The redirect.jsp works to get to the index.jsp page, but clicking the link on the index.jsp page gives me a 404 error.

The way I understand it, the welcome-file is the redirect.jsp (not sure how this file is handled and why it is not gine through the dispatcher - because it is a jsp?). This redirects to an htm file. The dispatcher finds a url mapping that matches the index.htm and calls the indexController, which sends to the "index" view, which is "/WEB-INF/jsp/" + index + ".jsp".

When Tomcat starts up I see the following messages:

```
Mapped URL path [/helloworld] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Mapped URL path [/helloworld/*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Mapped URL path [/index.htm] onto handler 'indexController'
```

Clicking the link in the index.jsp gives the following warning message:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WTSpring3/hello.htm]
```

My web files are layed out as follows:

```
web
  WEB-INF
    jsp
      hello.jsp
      index.jsp
    applicationContext.xml
    dispatcher-servlet.xml
    web.xml
  redirect.jsp
```

**redirect.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

**index.jsp** (this is the one I can never get to work. I am not sure if I have the link incorrect of the Spring setup).

```
<html><body>
<a href="hello.htm">Say Hello</a>
</body></html>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>${message}</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**
- note he url-pattern here is *.htm, which is what I use in my index.jsp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<context:component-scan base-package="net.mvp.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
 package net.mvp.spring3.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class HelloWorldController {

        @RequestMapping("hello")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
            String message = "Hallo Asgard";
            return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try maybe <a href="hello">Say Hello</a>, not sure tho.

Comment: Do you have any views.xml file with your jsp files?

Comment: To begin try to change your redirect.jsp content whit the clickable link:
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index - ViralPatel.net</title>
<a href="hello.htm">Say Hello</a>

Try and say if it work...if this version work it means that the problem is in the automatic redirect and not in your application logic

Answer (score 1):

Add a new bean to dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="helloWorldController" 
    class="net.mvp.spring3.controller.HelloWorldController" />
```

replace your bean with id urlMapping with the given below code

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
         <prop key="hello.htm">helloWorldController</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Note : **No** need to change the `@RequestMapping("hello")`

Comment: This is becoming more and more frustrating. I tried modifying the RequestMapping but it did nothing different. The error message is the same. It says  WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WTSpring3/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'. This is the part I am stuck on. It was my understanding that the Controller/RequestMapping portion creates the mapping for any url begininning with "hello" to map to the function. And every example I see does it a little different so, if I try to pull pieces from different examples it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways to do this but this is how i learned it, with view beans.
What happens is the following:

1. the user clicks a link with a certain name i.e. www.yoursite.com/*hello*
2. spring looks for '*hello*' in the requestmappings.
3. if the requestmapping is found, the corresponding method is executed.
4. that method returns a ModelAndView containing the alias(*hello*) of an url(WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp) that must be defined in the views.xml that is in the same location as your jsp files.
5. finally the page from the url(WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp) of the alias *hello* is shown to the user.

The views.xml defines the aliases for the urls of the different jsp files. So in that file you say that *hello* corresponds to *WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp*.

It looks something along these lines:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="excelViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/views.xml"/>
</bean>

<!-- in views.xml -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="hello" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView">
    <property name="hello" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

The requestmapping in your controller looks the same:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("hello") // what the user calls for, the request
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hallo Asgard";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message); // the response
        //"hello" in ModelAndView is the same "hello" as the one in views.xml
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: I had not heard of the views.xml file before. from what you wrote it sounds like what you are describing are what the annotations and the viewResolver are supposed to be doing? I tried adding the views.xml file in the jsp filder anyway, but got the same results.  BTW, none of the examples I have seen on the net or in tutorials have used a views.xml file either. But it was worth a try. :-)

Comment: @user1777296 sorry, i forgot to tell you that you need the XmlViewResolver for that.

Comment: you can also checkout http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html where it explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change hello.htm filename to hello2.jsp or something like this? I mean, try to use different name from request mapping.

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("hello") // what the user calls for, the request
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hallo Asgard";
        return new ModelAndView("hello2", "message", message); // the response
        //"hello" in ModelAndView is the same "hello" as the one in views.xml
    }
}
```

hello2.jsp

```
<html>
<body>${message}</body>
</html>
```